# Setting up S3 to host 'wp-content' folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, amazon-s3, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

If this is not the right SE to post the question, please kindly direct me to the right one.

I've seen configuration of setting up S3 to host `wp-content` folder, what are the advantages of doing so? and possibly what are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is a pretty good reference for using S3 and Wordpress.

[Wordpress S3 Guide](https://www.codeinwp.com/blog/wordpress-s3-guide/)

It calls out some very good advantages to using S3 with Wordpress:

> - Reduced requests to server – because your server no longer has to deliver media files (or potentially assets), you can reduce your page load times.
> - More affordable storage – if you’re butting up against your host’s storage limits, I can almost guarantee that S3’s storage prices are cheaper than what your host will charge.
> - Detached media – because your media files are detached from your site, it’s a heckuva lot easier to move your WordPress site around (like between hosts). You’re basically just moving the PHP files, which takes up almost no space.
> - Scalability – because Amazon S3 powers the entire Internet (ok, that’s a bit of hyperbole), you can be pretty confident that Amazon can scale with whatever’s happening to your site.

You can also use CloudFront.

A couple of disadvantages spring to mind

The first is performance, and the second is security.  In reverse order: you'd be  using a public S3 bucket.  You need to be cautious about what is stored in that bucket.

From the site below it looks like there are performance differences between using a web server to serve the content and S3.  I'd recommend experimenting with a WP server and S3 to see which is best for you.  It could be combination of S3 and CloudFront.

[Shouldn't Serve Assets on S3](https://deliciousbrains.com/shouldnt-serve-assets-s3/)